# Set Video Status as Inactive when direct upload a video on youPHPtube

Tags: php, youtube

I am setting videos on youPHPtube. During this, I was stuck in a little issue. I want Every uploaded video status as inactive instead of active. After that Admin can change the status of the video.

I have a lot of search about it and found a single thing which is that after **encoding,**  the status of video can be changed by going to Settings > General settings > Encoder > makeVideosInactiveAfterEncode, But I need this after direct upload.

Thanks to everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. I am going to share the solution here so that others who faced the same can easily resolve the issue.
You can go to the plugin menu and activate **CustomizeAdvanced (CustomizeAdvanced)** plugin
and then check the **makeVideosInactiveAfterEncode** option by going to **Edit parameter** section of the plugin.
The credit of this solution goes to the DanielnetoDotCom who is the collaborator of YouPHPTube-Encoder thread on Github.
Regards,
zain